# Как получить адрес локального файла (IOS)

Tags: ios

Пользователь сфоткал, нажимает на кнопку поиска похожих картинок.

Проблема:у гугла есть URL `google.com/searchbyimage&image_url=` полсе равно я должен вставить урл картинки чтоб обратном вызовом он мне выдал результат похожих картинок

Comment: а как вы сами находите этот файл? и почему нужно на URL переводит? что бы скачали из телефона?

Comment: Задумка:Пользователь сфоткал,нажимает на кнопку поиска похожих картинок.Проблема:у гугла есть URL https://www.google.com/searchbyimage&image_url= полсе равно я должен вставить урл картинки чтоб обратном вызовом он мне выдал результат похожих картинок

Comment: @Mersi, так исправьте вопрос, чтобы в нём было то, что вас интересует. для этого нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: сделаем проще: то, что вы пытаетесь сделать скорее всего работать не будет. у гугла нет доступа к вашему локальному файлу, даже если вы и пропишете путь. на ваш вопрос: получить путь к файлу `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myImage" ofType:@"png"];`.  Мне кажется, вам лучше посомтреть как работает соответствующий API и передавать картинку с его помощью

Comment: а по этому `google.com/searchbyimage&image_url=` есть какая то документация? не могу найти

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться бесплатным файлообменником с соответствующим api. Заливаете картинку, а затем даёте гуглу ссылку на картинку в этом файлообменнике.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: вы б хотя бы предложили какой то обменник с простым upload api (желательно с примером кода)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko специально не хотел этого делать, потому что таких файлообменников просто куча и нагуглить их не составляет труда и рекламировать один из них смысла нет. Но если Вам так уж тяжело набрать строку текста в поиске, то пожалуйста https://www.flickr.com/services/api/